# Using tokens under exposed views filter

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have created a view with an exposed filter. In my display I have an Using tokens section that I do not want to display:
[image]

Using the theme developer this is the closest I can get to it:
[image]

So it seems to part of views bulk operations. How can I get rid of this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to overide a function in my template.php in my theme:

```
function blogbuzz_views_bulk_operations_fields_action_form($form) {
  $output = '';
  $access = user_access('Use PHP input for field settings (dangerous - grant with care)');
  if ($access && $form['#settings']['php_code']) {
    $output .= t('<h3>Using the Code widget</h3>
                  <ul>
                  <li>Will override the value specified in the Field widget.</li>
                  <li>Should include &lt;?php ?&gt; delimiters.</li>
                  <li>If in doubt, refer to <a target="_blank" href="@link_devel">devel.module</a> \'Dev load\' tab on a content page to figure out the expected format.</li>
                  </ul>', array('@link_devel' => 'http://www.drupal.org/project/devel')
    );
  }
}
```